# Median and Binary Classification in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of log transformed IC50 values for around 100 drugs (rows) for 20 cell lines (columns) and another column with the median values for each drug. I've attached a sample table below (I hope it's clear!)

```
           MCF-7         T47D         Kuramochhi         Median
Cisplatin  -1.45    -0.397799999    -2.629980996    -1.457715002
AICAR       9.684057    8.350465       9.559031         7.783897
```

Basically what I'd like to do is assign a value of 0 or 1 if a cell line has a value greater than the median (1) or less than the median (0) for each drug (100 drugs in total). I'm quite stuck on how to get started with this and how the script should look. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Very unclear, to me anyway. What is this "other column" you are referring to? What is "median(1)" and "median(0)"? The use of pronouns and adjectives like "other" is a barrier to unambiguous communications about data management problems. I'm guessing you actually want the results of `apply(df, function(col) as.numeric(col > median (col) ))`. I don't think you actually need to use your "other column".

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear... what I meant is I have the median values for each drug (i.e. for cisplatin it's -1.4577) and what I'd like to do is for each cell line assign a value of 0 if the IC50 values is less than the median value, or 1 if it is greater. So for example, for the cisplatin drug Kuramochi would be assigned a value of 0 since it's IC50 value is below the median. I hope it's clear now!

Comment: Well, the code I suggested should deliver that result; did you try it?

Comment: So what exactly is the desired output for the sample input you provided?

Comment: I'd like to have an output table just containing 0's and 1's depending on if a cell line's IC50 value is above or below the median value for a certain drug.

Comment: and thanks for the suggestion BondedDust, I'll give it a try

Comment: So you want a table of the exact same dimension as the input? Again, please be explicit.

Comment: Hi MrFlick, yes the output table should be the same dimensions as the input.

Comment: Hi BondedDust, I tried the code you suggested but I get the following error message: Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default. What do I need to specify as the "FUN" arguement? Thanks for any help!